# How to compare the value of one row with the upper row in one column of an ordered table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL that contains the GPS points from cell phones. It has an integer column that stores epoch (the number of seconds from 1960). I want to order the table based on time (epoch column), then, break the trips to sub trips when there is no GPS record for more than 2 minutes.

I did it with GeoPandas. However, it is too slow. I want to do it inside the PostgreSQL. How can I compare each row of the ordered table with the previous row (to see if the epoch has a difference of 2 minutes or more)?
In fact, I do not know how to compare each row with the upper row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to order the table based on time (epoch column), then, break the trips to sub trips when there is no GPS record for more than 2 minutes.

After comparing to the previous (or next) row, with the window function `lag()` (or `lead()`), form groups based on the gaps to get sub trip numbers:

```sql
SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE step) OVER (PARTITION BY trip ORDER BY timestamp_epoch) AS sub_trip
FROM  (
   SELECT *
       , (timestamp_epoch - lag(timestamp_epoch) OVER (PARTITION BY trip ORDER BY timestamp_epoch)) > 120 AS step
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub;
```

Further reading:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(timestamp_epoch) over (partition by trip order by timestamp_epoch) as last_timestamp_epoch
      from t
     ) t
where last_timestamp_epoch < timestamp_epoch - 120
```